# Why is my loss function value increasing with each epoch?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tf.keras

I have a multiclass classification problem and would like to train a neural network model. I am using TensorFlow and Keras. This is the [dataset link](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/forest-cover-type-dataset).

There are 7 different target labels. I have been told that the last layer of the network should include 7 nodes and activation function as softmax. Also I am transforming the target labels to one-hot encoding format and using 'categorical_crossentropy' as loss function.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, test_size=0.7, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

y_train = tf.one_hot(y_train,7,)
y_test = tf.one_hot(y_test,7,)

# Define the model architecture
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=128)

# Evaluate the model on the test data
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
```

As you can see, loss is increasing with every epoch. I am not sure what is wrong and could not figure it out.
[loss value for each epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npdJY.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check y_pred and y_true arrays to ensure outputs. They should look like following:

y_pred = [0.22, 0.32, 0.13, .., .., .., 0.01] (values can change)
y_true = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

If there is no problem, check following point:

2. Your architecture has input with size 10, but dataset contains 55 columns 1 is y and 54 are feature. If there is no enough feature, model can not learn lots of details. Change input size and provide more features to model and add one more hidden layer to increase model capability.

Comment: Hi @emredo ! y_pred values are not similar to your examples unfortunetly but i am not sure why this is happening. This was the code that to get the y_pred values:

`history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=128)`
`y_pred = model.predict(X_test)`
`print("---y_pred---")`
`print(y_pred)`
`print("---y_test---")`
`print(y_test)`
And this is the following output. [output](https://imgur.com/a/dLLYjLR).

Comment: output contains lots of samples, so output confused you, but there is no wrong thing with shape, etc. you feed 406708 samples at same time, and you get 406708 predictions. No problem with this. 

BUT your model outputs very interesting. I performed with pytorch, i am getting following numbers for each class:

```
y_pred tensor([[0.1117, 0.2405, 0.1039, 0.0796, 0.3167, 0.1184, 0.0292]])
y_true tensor([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
y_pred_sum tensor(1.)
```

Your each predictions summation should be equal to 1.

Comment: maybe you are performing np.argmax to predictions before checking?